# Filtering NSArray of NSmanagedObject with one-to-may relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have 3 entities, "Bar", "Waiter", "Product" the relationship is as follows, 
A "Bar" has one to many relationship with "Waiter" and the same from Waiter to Product.

I have an array of Waiters working on a Bar, and I want to filter the waiters based on if they served a certain Product.

Im trying to filter the array of all the Waiters in a bar, [bar.toWaiter allObjects]

So far I've tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"toProduct.endSaleDate > %@ AND toProduct.published == YES", [NSDate date]];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY toProduct.endSaleDate > %@ AND ANY toProduct.published == YES", [NSDate date]];
```

I only want those waiters who have a Product that has "published" to YES and endSaleDate in the future. What Im getting is Waiters that have either a Product published or a product with a future date.

How can I achieve what Im looking for.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If published is a Boolean attribute, try checking toProduct.published == 1

Comment: Is that the only problem?

Comment: That's my guess. Booleans are stored as NSNumbers in Core Data and can really trip you up. Apple suggests using [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] when creating your predicate. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: Bools can be a bit tricky in NSPredicate, especially if you have some that are null, as opposed to always having a true/false value by default.

Comment: I changed that and the same result, my guess is that the problem is with the ANY, it some how treats the AND as a OR and therefore doesnt really filter anything

Comment: @MikeTaverne By the way, you can now use literal syntax to create and initialize an `NSNumber` instance, so in this case simply `@YES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the predicate is interpreted as "give me waiters which have ANY published product and ANY product with a future date". But it does not require that *the same* product fulfils *both* conditions.

You can use a [SUBQUERY](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW21) to ensure that:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"@"SUBQUERY(toProduct, $product, $product.published == 1 AND $product.endSaleDate > %@).@count > 0"];
```